King post truss question
Problem:
Sagging roof in the middle of a garage.
I could sister the bottom cord and/or add struts from bottom cord to the rafters but room is very limited.
Question:
After jacking the trusses at the sagging part of the roof.  Would tying the trusses together at the King posts with 2x6/8 help give structural support and keep the roof from sagging once the jacks are removed?

you need to move the load out to the edges, which is what struts to the rafters would do
